# Why attacks like Rotation, Scaling, Croping is not changing the value of performance parameters such as PSNR and MSE

Tags: image, matlab, encryption, watermark, mse

I am doing a project on Image watermarking using Discrete Wavelet Transform(DWT) and Encryption. It was carried out in the following steps

1.) Selected host image (Image in which watermark will be hidden).
2.) Selected the watermark.
3.) Encrypted watermark using the following code(Matlab Code)

```
    b= strcat(b,a);   %String Concatenation
    c=imread(b);     %Image is read and stored in the variable c
    [p,q,r]=size(c); %displaying the dimensions of Image
    % Cipher watermark %
    % this is a randperm method which generated  random values
    scrambleOrder = randperm(p*q); 
    redChannel = c(:, :, 1);  % Extraction of red channel
    greenChannel = c(:, :, 2); % Extraction of green channel
    blueChannel = c(:, :, 3); % Extraction of blue channel
    redChannel = redChannel(scrambleOrder); % Red channel scrambling
    greenChannel = greenChannel(scrambleOrder); % Green channel scrambling
    blueChannel = blueChannel(scrambleOrder); % Blue channel scrambling
    redChannel = reshape(redChannel, [p,q]);  % reshaping red channel 
    greenChannel = reshape(greenChannel, [p,q]); % reshaping green channel 
    blueChannel = reshape(blueChannel, [p,q]); % reshaping blue channel 
    s = cat(3, redChannel, greenChannel, blueChannel); % cat command for concatenation
```

4.) Watermarked using DWT.

5.) Recover the Encrypted watermark using recovery formula.

6.) Decryption of watermark using the below code.

```
     % it will generate the 2 columns having maximum value u*v and  where u and v are dimensions(width and height) of recovered watermark from watermarked image. 
     recoverOrder = zeros([u*v], 2); 
     recoverOrder(:, 1) = 1 : (u*v); % make the first column value from 1: u*v 
     recoverOrder(:, 2) = scrambleOrder; % make second column value of randon permutation generated during encryption
     newOrder1 = sortrows(recoverOrder, 2); % sort rows of column1 and column 2
     newOrder = newOrder1(:,1); Eliminate column2
     redChannel = redChannel(newOrder); % New order value into red channel
     greenChannel = greenChannel(newOrder); % New order value into green channel
     blueChannel = blueChannel(newOrder); % New order value into blue channel
     redChannel = reshape(redChannel, [u, v]); % reshape red channel
     greenChannel = reshape(greenChannel, [u, v]); % reshape green channel
     blueChannel = reshape(blueChannel, [u, v]); % reshape blue channel
     D = cat(3, redChannel, greenChannel, blueChannel); % cat RGB and store it in D
```

My Question is that I had made many attacks on Watermarked Image like Rotation, scaling, croping  but PSNR and MSE between (Watermark and Decrypted watermark) is not changing.
I think during decryption, I used same rand permutation that is used to **ENCRYPT** the image.

Any valuable suggestion would make to understand the reason behind that.

Comment: It seems you'd have to store that `scrambleOrder` in the encrypted image file, which leads you to A) increase image size substantially/remember a huge key! B) no safety at all since the key is there anyways... ; also, this question doesn't seem specific or asks about a problem. Generally, on SO, questions are for asking questions about a specific problem that you are stuck on and have worked on.